# Translation of "contact info"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

What is the best way to say *contact info* in Spanish (as in a list of phone numbers, email addresses, postal addresses, etc. of a person or business)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually "Información de contacto"

But you don't ask somebody else for his/her "Información de contacto". You have to ask for a particular item, as in: "¿Me puedes dar tu número telefónico?"

Comment: But you can be asked to provide your *Información de contacto* when filling in a form, for example.

Comment: @Gonzalo Yep. It is very usual in forms and written materials (brochures, etc.)

Answer (score 9):

If you want a literal translation, "información de contacto".  As in ¿Cuál es tu información de contacto?.  But more likely to go with "¿Cuál es tu número de teléfono?"

Answer (score 3):

I have heard this referred to, collectively, as *datos*, although that's really a broader term, and can refer to birth date, height, social security number, or any other *data* about a person.

Comment: Referring to people, "datos" is _very_ colloquial.

Comment: I'm sure I've heard/seen *datos* like this in Mexico. Remember *info* in English is also *very colloquial*.

Comment: @hippietrail: But not _quite_ as colloquial as "Give me your digits."

Comment: @Flimzy: Hand over the dice!

Comment: @belisarius: I don't think it's as colloquial as you think in all locations.  Last night when paying for a car repair, the cashier asked if my "datos" were all correct. And again this morning when shipping something via UPS, the clerk asked me to fill in my "datos."  So the phrase is clearly used in "professional" transactions here in Guadalajara.

Comment: @Flimzy I think those are good examples of colloquial usage.  I'd not ask for his "datos" to the prince of whales :)

Comment: @belisarius: Most whales don't have contact info ;)

Comment: @Flimzy Of course not :http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhzuE6V9usQ#t=60s :)